# Understanding Git Rebase

Tags: git, git-branch, rebase, branching-and-merging

Here is my structure of Git repositories (local and remote).

**Local**

- master
- my-workingcopy

**Remote**

- origin/master
- origin/my-workingcopy
- origin/others-workingcopy

Below is status of how many commits each branches ahead of relatively.

```
git rev-list --left-right --count master...origin/master
0  15    

git rev-list --left-right --count my-workingcopy...origin/master
40  15

git rev-list --left-right --count my-workingcopy...origin/my-workingcopy
0  0
```

Now I want to bring those latest changes(15 commits) on the master, in to *my-workingcopy*. So I do following steps.

```
git checkout master
git pull origin master
git checkout my-workingcopy
git rebase master
```

So I end up with following state.

```
git rev-list --left-right --count master...origin/master
0  0

git rev-list --left-right --count my-workingcopy...origin/master
40  0    

git rev-list --left-right --count my-workingcopy...origin/my-workingcopy
15  7
```

Over here, I am having trouble with the last command where it shows *my-workingcopy* is behind from *origin/my-workingcopy* by 7 commits. It is understandable that it is ahead from remote as a result of rebase, but what causes it to get behind from the remote, given that they were in sync before doing the rebase.

Any clarification on this would be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When doing a rebase, you are rewriting history on your current branch.

You rewind your current branch to a point where it was equal to the other branch (basically putting the commits on the current branch aside), and then apply the commits that are on your current branch, but not on the other branch. With each commit, git might automerge, so it might not be exactly equal to what it was before the rebase (as the starting point is different).

It might be that 7 of your 40 commits needed to be changed, so they are no longer the same as they were when they were last pushed. Shouldn't be cause for worry. But if you get an error when you push, it might be time to stop and rethink things.

Comment: Really eloquently put. I was about to answer the question but your answer is clearer than what I was thinking

Comment: Thanks for the answer! My concern is that when I push it to my remote and if I end up getting merge conflict, then do I need to resolve all those conflicts again(which I already resolved while rebasing with master).

Comment: With the commands you posted, the chances of something getting messed up is very, very small. But I don't really understand the output you are getting either, it would make more sense if it was `22 7` (= 15 from master, and 7 on each side that got rewritten).

Comment: But when I think of it: I usually use rebase when pulling. I use merge when it is two different branches. Don't recall the reason, but I might have experienced some strangeness like this before. Try a regular push, if that gives and error and you are sure that your local changes are correct (and there are no other pushes made), do a force-push.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that the revisions have *no relation* to the original revisions.... to git they are different revisions.... so on the origin branch you have the original 7 revisions.... on your local branch you have *other* 7 revisions (plus the 8 coming from master, I would assume) different from the 7 on the remote branch.